# Bootstrap btn-default in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I can't change button design in for firefox

MY CSS:

```
.btn-changed-orange{ background:orange;}
```

MY HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-changed-orange">CLICK HERE</button>
</div>
```

Button is orange on every browser but not in Firefox. What is wrong? when I check in Firebug, Firefox even does not see this class in the CSS window.

Time when IE was the worst browser pass away and now I must do every think different for firefox?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl+F5?

Comment: yes, many times.. clear cache, make new blank file with only this button ... but in firefox button is always default.

Comment: ok i had error in CSS - some " ' " were lost in class ... i'm always make sites in RoR soo it throw errors but with only html and css don't.